# Relation between derivatives and discrete derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Let us define the "discrete derivative"

$$ \Delta f( x) = f(x + 1) - f( x ) $$

and recursively $\Delta ^n f\left( x \right) = \Delta \left( {\Delta ^{n - 1} f\left( x \right)} \right)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Is there some simple relation between $\Delta ^n f$ and the standard derivative $f^{(n)}$? Can we write a Taylor series expansion (say about 0) of $f$ in terms of discrete derivatives?

Comment: FYI, this is usually called "finite differences". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using the [Stirling numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) one has $$ \frac{1}{k!} \frac{d^k}{dx^k} f(x) = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{s(n,k)}{n!} \Delta^{n} f(x) $$ and
$$ \frac{1}{k!} \Delta^{k} f(x)  = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{S(n,k)}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)$$

Edit: The Newton Series are defined as $$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}   \binom{x-a}{k} \: \Delta^k f(a) $$ some examples include: $$   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \binom{n}{2k}  = 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \:  \cos(\frac{\pi n}{4}) \\   \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} \binom{n}{k}  = H_n $$ where $H_n$ are the Harmonic numbers.

Comment: I didn't know these formulas. Do you have a reference where I can find them established ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm not sure of a reference that treats them thoroughly but I personally found them in the *NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions* section 26.8 pg. 625

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: It should be underlined for the OP that these infinite summation formulas will be of limited practical interest...

Comment: If OP wants a series based solely upon forward differences, see the Newton Series, which is the forward difference analogue to the Taylor series which Newton propounded in his *Principia Mathemtica*

Comment: @DecarbonatedOdes thank you, this is interesting! You're right that with infinite series becomes hard to handle in practical situations. Could you add some elaboration on the Newton Series applied to this case? what can we write using that then?

Comment: very good (+1) you may be interested in the answer to this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306828)

Comment: @JeanMarie: I think the classic *[Calculus of Finite Differences](https://bookstore.ams.org/chel-33)* is a most valuable reference. You can find e.g. the $n$-th differences using Stirling numbers in chapter IV: Stirling's numbers, $\S$ 56: Derivatives expressed by differences.

Comment: @epi163sqrt thank you very much for the reference.